# scrollTop off by 1 pixel in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Similar to an issue described [here](http://www.sikosoft.com/item/firefox_3_goes_1_pixel_out_of_bounds_with_jquery_scrolltop_and_height), in certain situations, `$(window).scrollTop()` will be off by one in Firefox.

I'm using this to detect if the vertical scrollbar has reached the bottom:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{
    // bottom reached
}
```

This works. But I just discovered by accident, that it only works most of the times. Here's the log from a case where it goes wrong. `scrollTop` is saying I've scrolled 611 pixels, `difference` is saying I am able to scroll 612 pixels.

```
scrollTop: 611
doc height: 933
win height: 321
difference: 612
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Or is this a Firefox issue? In the latter case I guess I can change it to check if it's 5 or less pixels remaining. But if the code is wrong I'd like to fix it.

Comment: Can't you just write: `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) { ... }` ?

Comment: @chester1000 No, because if you look at the values, `scrollTop` < `difference`.

Comment: Just a thought, this could be caused by sub-pixel rendering. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/17/sub-pixel-rendering-and-the-css-object-model.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1):

use below code it works

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though that's a workaround similar to the one described in the question.